# Because azuredevops_group has "for_each" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances - Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, hashicorp

Im receiving the error saying that

> Because azuredevops_group.group has "for_each" set, its attributes
> must be accessed on specific instances.

so my module block looks like this

```
module "groups" {
  source = "./groups"

  for_each = toset(local.all_groups)

  object_ids = data.azuread_groups.current_ad_group.object_ids
  project_id = data.azuredevops_project.dataanalytics.id
  group_name = each.value
}

locals {
  group_ids = {
    for group in local.all_groups :
    group => module.groups[group].group_origin_id
  }

  group_ids_x = {
    for group in local.all_groups :
    group => module.groups[group].group_id
  }
}
```

which will call this resource block

```
resource "azuredevops_group" "group" {
  # scope        = var.project_id
  for_each          = toset(var.object_ids)
  origin_id         = each.key
  # display_name = var.group_name
  # description  = "This group is created by Terraform"
}
```

but inside the module I also define the local variables based on the output of the `"azuredevops_group"` and this is where it goes wrong I think.

```
output "group_origin_id" {
  value = azuredevops_group.group.origin_id
}

output "group_id" {
  value = azuredevops_group.group.id
}
```

Im pretty new to terraform and dont udnerstand how to define the output in case I use the `for_each` loop.

I tried something like this but did not work.

> output "group_origin_id" {   value =
> azuredevops_group.group.origin_id[*] }

Comment: does not work, syntaxt is not correct

Comment: the `[*]` syntax does not work in resources with `for_each`

Comment: @play_something_good try to create a map of group resources within the module using a for_each loop and then define outputs to access specific attributes like origin_id and id. In the root configuration, map the module outputs to local variables or use them directly based on your requirements.